# Extending spark connectors versus Providing utility library

Tags: apache-spark

Had a design question around wether it’s a good idea to write wrappers over all existing spark connectors for adding some functionality/improving usability in terms of options passed to the connector. In contrast to providing utility libraries that takes parameters and calls the underlying connectors as it is.

Example:
Option 1:
Extends snowflake-connector to add some options and use it as:

> > spark.read.format(“my-snowflake”).option(“myoption”, “”)

Option 2:
Write a utility

> > util.readWithMyOption()

Also what kind of logic can be put inside the DataSourceV2 connector? Is it a good idea to manipulate/change the incoming dataset inside the connector

Thanks.